# What is a more efficient way to calculate cumulative quantile than cumquant?

Tags: r, datatable, cumulative-sum, quantile

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative quantile (10 percentile, 25 percentile, etc.) over a column in a large dataset (over 10 million).

I tried to use the function `cumquant` from the cumstats package but it takes long (longer than an hour; a toy test shows that it takes more than 40 seconds to obtain results for a vector with 100,000 values (e.g. `cumquant(1:100000,p=0.1)`).

Is there a more efficient way to calculate it using `data.table` (or others)?

Comment: What about stats:::quantile function doesn't give you what you need?

Comment: Is that working cumulatively in a dataset?